# RoutingError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have defined the route
`get '/finish_cur_activity/:act_id' => 'activities#finish_cur_activity',   as: :finish_cur_activity` in routes.rb and I am trying to use it like this `$.get('/finish_cur_activity/', {act_id: currentActivityId})` but nothing happens and I am getting the following error on the console:
 `Started GET "/finish_cur_activity/?act_id=3" for ::1 at 2017-03-08 23:03:09 -0800 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/finish_cur_activity"):`

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your URL is `/finish_cur_activity/:act_id`, not `/finish_cur_activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that

```
 $.get('/finish_cur_activity/' + currentActivityId)
```

It should generate proper URL and it will work fine!

If you use ES6 you can use

```
$.get(`/finish_cur_activity/${currentActivityId}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass id like

```
$.get('/finish_cur_activity/' + currentActivityId)
```

In your code you passing `id` as a extra parameter, that's why its add parameter using `?`

```
"/finish_cur_activity/?act_id=3"
```

This Url should be following

```
"/finish_cur_activity/3"
```

In controller id `3` will automatic consider as `act_id`

```
params[:act_id]
```